# New value with one similar column and on different column in R

Tags: r

I need to mutate a new value: "new_value" based on the same ID "ï..record_id". I need all with the same ID to have the same value in "date_eortc".

My data1 looks likes:

```
data1 %>%
  select( ï..record_id, dato1, galbeta_date, date_eortc)


>    ï..record_id      dato1 galbeta_date date_eortc
1              1       <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
2              1       <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
3              1       <NA>   2018-01-16       <NA>

.....
99            10 2018-02-07         <NA> 2017-12-27
100           10       <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
101           10       <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
102           10       <NA>   2017-12-19       <NA>
103           10       <NA>   2017-12-26       <NA>
104           10       <NA>   2017-12-29       <NA>
105           10       <NA>   2018-01-02       <NA>
106           10       <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
107           10       <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
108           11       <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
```

In this case I need all with "ï..record_id"=10, then date date eortc should all be "2017-12-27"

So it would looks like:

```
    ï..record_id      dato1 galbeta_date date_eortc
99            10 2018-02-07         <NA> 2017-12-27
100           10       <NA>         <NA> 2017-12-27
101           10       <NA>         <NA> 2017-12-27
102           10       <NA>   2017-12-19 2017-12-27
103           10       <NA>   2017-12-26 2017-12-27
104           10       <NA>   2017-12-29 2017-12-27
105           10       <NA>   2018-01-02 2017-12-27
106           10       <NA>         <NA> 2017-12-27
107           10       <NA>         <NA> 2017-12-27
108           11       <NA>         <NA>       <NA>
```

I have tried to make an ifelse statement, but it's not the right one...

```
data2 <- data1 %>%
  mutate(new_value= ifelse(ï..record_id == ï..record_id , date_eortc, NA))
```

I hope it makes sense.
Thank you for your time,
Julie

Comment: It would be better if you could share a reproducible excerpt of your data so that we can use it to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We could do a group_by the `ï..record_id` and `fill` the NA elements in 'date_eortic' with the non-NA adjacent element

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data1 %>%
   group_by(ï..record_id) %>%
   fill(date_eortic)
```